# Wrong dates in views 'Content: Created year + month' contextual filter

Tags: views

I have a view into which I'm trying to link to nodes via the date in the 'Authored on' date of that node.

I'm creating the nodes from another site and am wanting to reuse the dates upon which they were originally posted. In effect, I'm creating new nodes with dates from the past in the 'Authored on' field on each node.

I want to create a view block based upon the 'Authored on' date from the node, that groups the nodes by month. eg:

```
March 2015 (1)
February 2015 (3)
December 2014 (4)
```

etc...

I can create the view block with a Contextual filter of 'Content: Created year + month'

```
Display Summary
Sort order: descending
Sort by: date
Format: list
Display record count with link: checked
```

This all works fine, but the links that are created when I use this view block don't go to the posts in question, they simply return me to the entire list of nodes that make up this content type.

Do the link with the contextual filter 'Content: Created year + month' actually refer to the 'Authored on' date from the node?

Any thoughts would be really welcome.

Comment: I'd be surprised if Views generates a date-based link without you specifying this kind of behaviour. You may need to pull the aggregated date; then parse it into a year/month path pattern in the rewritten link. You can then pass this on to a second page view which returns results based on your url wildcards via contextual filters.